# Dynamically build SQL " OR " query in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I am having problem with my asp.net app, in which I am dynamically building SQL query where I am using WHERE clause and adding OR depending on the fields which is entered. here is the scenario.

I have a Four TextBox, out of 2 is DateTime

i would like to search in the database if there is a value in any one text-box and return the results that is bind to a GridView. Now, if there is more than one text-box value then i need to add that as well and build OR in where clause. if there are no values in any one of the text-box then need to return all the results. BUT i am having problem in building the query as i have to go through the if else loop to see if there is any value or null. here is my code.

```
          StringBuilder selectQuery = new StringBuilder();
          disCode = SearchTextCouponCode.Text;
          disName = SearchTextCouponName.Text;

          if(StartDate.SelectedDate != null)
                 startDate = StartDate.SelectedDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");

          if(EndDate.SelectedDate != null)     
                 endDate = EndDate.SelectedDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");


          // here is the main thing where i am getting the error
          if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(disCode))
          {
                 selectQuery.Append("DISCOUNTCode = '" + disCode + "'");

          }

          if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(disName))
          {
                 selectQuery.Append(" OR DISCOUNTName = '" + disName + "'");

          }

          if (startDate != "0001-01-01")
          {
                 selectQuery.Append(" OR StartDate = '" + startDate + "'");

          }

          if(endDate != "0001-01-01")
                 selectQuery.Append(" OR EndDate = '" + endDate + "'");


          // I am using Object Data Source and the method i am passing is taking care of the SQL injection     
          DataSourceDis.SelectParameters["sqlCriteria"].DefaultValue = selectQuery.ToString();
          GridDis.DataBind();
```

now, when i run the app, and leave the disCode text-box empty, then the query start with OR and gives me the error that incorrect syntax near where ..

please help.

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

i am calling another method after building up this query which is taking care of SQL Injection

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

Comment: Use parameterised queries. You can still build this up in the same way but concatenating textbox inputs directly into the query means you are vulnerable to SQL injection

Comment: SQL INJECTION SQL INJECTION SQL INJECTION why is this still such a problem???

Comment: i am calling another method after building up this query which is taking care of SQL Injection

Comment: @patel.milanb I'd be very wary. I'm willing to bet that that subsequent method is flawed

Comment: You'd be a lot better of sanitising your inputs **before** you build the query than afterwards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set all lines to have `" OR "` at the end (instead of the start), such as...

```
selectQuery.Append("DISCOUNTCode = '" + disCode + "' OR ");
```

And then before using the `.ToString()` have...

```
if(selectQuery.Length > 0)
{
  selectQuery.Length -= 4;
}
```

Comment: You're welcome @Patel, glad I could help - as I said in the comments on the question, I would seriously consider sanitising your input **before** you build the selectQuery, as it's a lot easier than doing it afterwards

Answer (score 3):

The easiest thing you could do is change `WHERE` to:

```
WHERE 1=0
```

And then ensure all of your `WHERE` conditions start with `OR`

---

As Richard has pointed out however, this is not best practice, and you would be better using a stored procedure or LINQ. Using stored procedures you could pass all these parameters to the procedure and then do something like:

```
AND (@disName IS NULL OR DiscountName=@disName)
```

Comment: If you use all "OR"s, then start with `WHERE 1=0` (else the 1=1 will accept everything, ignoring the real conditions).

Answer (score 1):

I'd generally do it like this;

```
var conds = new List<string> ();

     // here is the main thing where i am getting the error
      if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(disCode))
      {
             conds.Add("DISCOUNTCode = '" + disCode + "'");
      }

      if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(disName))
      {
             conds.Add("DISCOUNTName = '" + disName + "'");
      }

      if (startDate != "0001-01-01")
      {
             conds.Add("StartDate = '" + startDate + "'");
      }

      if(endDate != "0001-01-01")
             conds.Add("EndDate = '" + endDate + "'");

     selectQuery.Append(String.Join(" OR ",conds));
```

It's a bit hideous building queries like this - better to use prepared statements or LINQ or your own query building class.

Comment: if one of the field is empty then it will append OR at the end by doing this.

Comment: @patel.milanb it wouldn't - but anyway I changed my mind and my answer

Answer (score 1):

If you use the `WHERE 1=0 OR` solution, you may get performance impacts.

I'd recommend creating a variable to mark the conjunction and changing it when you add a condition

```
string conjuction = " ";
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(disCode)) 
{ 
             selectQuery.Append(conjunction);
             selectQuery.Append("DISCOUNTCode = '" + disCode + "'"); 
             conjuction = " OR ";              
} 

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(disName)) 
{ 
             selectQuery.Append(conjunction);
             selectQuery.Append("DISCOUNTName = '" + disName + "'"); 
              conjuction = " OR ";
}
```

etc.

I don't know where your inputs are coming from, but be aware of the potential for a SQL injection attack in your current code.

Comment: lets say, if the disCode is there and all the three parameter is empty then it will append OR in the end and will cause error.

Comment: @patel, I'm afraid you're wrong, it will work... this is quite a nice solution, although more complex than is strictly necessary

Comment: i dont understand, if disCode is "ABC" and there is no value for "disName" then the query will be like this where disCode = "ABC" OR

Comment: @patel, the `" OR "` is being set into the variable **after** the statement is appended, meaning that the variable will be appended **before the next** statement

Comment: @patel.milanb The conjuction only gets appended before the filters. It gets changed when a filter is set, but it is not appended.

Answer (score 0):

A valid Sql query `e.g. SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE WHERE Name = 'Hat' OR SURNAME = 'SOFT'`

Looks like you case when the query starts with OR your StringBuilder Appends the query like this 
`SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE WHERE OR SURNAME = 'SOFT'` and its invalid becuase the OR KEYWORD directly after WHERE

Comment: thats my point here...how do i stop OR coming at the beginning..i am using if else to see if there is value then add OR

Answer (score 0):

**when your disCode text-box is empty then Condition will be "OR DISCOUNTName" which is wrong you can not use "OR" after where**

```
     if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(disCode))
      {
             selectQuery.Append("DISCOUNTCode = '" + disCode + "'");

      }

      if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(disName))
      {
             selectQuery.Append(" OR DISCOUNTName = '" + disName + "'");

      }
```

Comment: I think the OP is aware of this... that's why they asked the question in the first place